# Nhibernate and linq problem

Tags: linq, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, nhibernate-3

I get the following expression:

```
_senderRepos.Get(s => s.User.Email == fromAddress);
```

which results in

```
could not resolve property: User.Email of: Module.Fax2Pdf.MailToFax.Models.Sender
```

class:

```
public class Sender
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Site Site { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" auto-import="true">
  <class name="Module.Fax2Pdf.MailToFax.Models.Sender, Module.Fax2Pdf" table="fax_allowed_senders">
    <id name="Id" column="id">
      <generator class="sequence">
        <param name="sequence">fax_allowed_senders_id_seq</param>
      </generator>
    </id>
    <many-to-one column="site_id" name="Site" />
    <many-to-one column="user_id" name="User" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And the User class DO have a Email property in it's mapping file. What am I doing wrong?

**Update, user mapping**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" auto-import="false">
  <class name="Gate.Users.User, Gate.Models" table="users">
    <id name="Id" column="id">
      <generator class="sequence">
        <param name="sequence">users_id_seq</param>
      </generator>
    </id>
    <many-to-one column="site_id" name="Site" />
    <property name="FirstName" column="first_name" type="String" length="30"/>
    <property name="LastName" column="last_name" type="String" length="30"/>
    <property name="CanDelete" column="can_delete" type="boolean" />
    <property name="Email" column="email" type="String" length="255"/>
    <property name="Department" column="department" type="String" length="30"/>
    <property name="Title" column="title" type="String" length="30"/>
    <many-to-one class="Gate.Extensions.Extension, Gate.Models" column="extension_id" name="Extension" />
    <property name="Status" column="status" type="integer" />
    <property name="CreatedAt" column="created_at" />
    <property name="UpdatedAt" column="updated_at" />
    <property name="TimeZone" column="timezone" type="integer" />
    <property name="MiddleNames" column="middle_names" type="string" />
    <property name="NamePrefix" column="name_prefix" type="string" />
    <property name="NameSuffix" column="name_suffix" type="string" />
    <property name="DateOfBirth" column="dob" />
    <property name="RemovedAt" column="removed_at" />
    <property name="ProxyMedia" column="proxy_media" type="boolean" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: There's not enough information in your question.  Maybe providing the user class definitions and mapping would help, as a start.

Comment: What implementation of Linq provider do you use? Some providers have problems with subproperties.

Comment: I use the one included with nhibernate

Comment: Please post your User mapping file

Comment: oops, added the incorrect user mapping. fixed.

Comment: Hmm, inside your repository are you using session.Query or session.Linq to expose the linq provider?

Comment: I've uppgraded to latest nhibernate now (3.0.400). No difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies. I was using `QueryOver` on the `Get` method in the Repository and `Query` for everything else. It works when I switched to `Query`.

Answer (score 1):

What if you called `.Expand()` on your `IQueryable` first?

So, assuming you had a session, it might look like this:

```
var senders = 
    (from sender in session.Query<Sender>().Expand("User")
     where sender.User.Email == fromAddress
     select sender);
```

Unfortunately that requires you to import an NHibernate extension method.

Comment: Honestly, this was a shot in the dark, and I don't think it will work.  You're supposed to use `Expand` to "bring back" more data for accessing later.  The `where` clause, however, should work fine just how you have it.